# PDO prepared statement update not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

am new to prepared statements and PDO. I have a script with two prepared statements, the insert statement works fine, yet the update does not. It returns no errors and displays the success message, yet it doesn't update the database.

Here is the code that doesn't work. Any help wouild be much appreciated. Thanks

```
$queryString="UPDATE team_directory SET team_name=':team_name',
aka=':aka',
website=':website',
main_contact=':main_contact',
phone=':phone',
email=':email',
other=':other',
np1=':np1',
np2=':np2',
np3=':np3',
np4=':np4',
np5=':np5',
np6=':np6',
np7=':np7',
np8=':np8',
np9=':np9',
np10=':np10',
np11=':np11',
np12=':np12'
where team_id=':team_id'";

$query=$database->prepare($queryString);
$query->execute(array(':team_name'=>$team_name,
':aka'=>$aka,
':website'=>$website,
':main_contact'=>$main_contact,
':phone'=>$phone,
':email'=>$email,
':other'=>$other,
':np1'=>$np1,
':np2'=>$np2,
':np3'=>$np3,
':np4'=>$np4,
':np5'=>$np5,
':np6'=>$np6,
':np7'=>$np7,
':np8'=>$np8,
':np9'=>$np9,
':np10'=>$np10,
':np11'=>$np11,
':np12'=>$np12,
':team_id'=>$team_id));

if ($query->errorCode()==0) {




    echo "<p>Team amended successfully, <a href=\"select_amend_team.php\">Amend Another</a>    </p>
    <p><a href=\"admin_team_directory.php\">Team Directory</a></p>
    <p><a href=\"admin_home.php\">Admin Homepage</a></p>";
}

else {
    $errors=$query->errorInfo();
    echo ($errors[2]);
}
```

Comment: `:placeholders` don't belong enclosed in single quotes. That would make them literal string values.

Comment: even in the execute array? My insert staement has them in quotes but that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply take the placeholders (your to-be-used prepared statement markers for variables) out of those evil quotes:

```
$queryString="UPDATE team_directory SET team_name = :team_name,
  aka = :aka,
  website = :website,
  main_contact = :main_contact,
  phone = :phone,
  email = :email,
  other = :other,
  np1 = :np1,
  np2 = :np2,
  np3 = :np3,
  np4 = :np4,
  np5 = :np5,
  np6 = :np6,
  np7 = :np7,
  np8 = :np8,
  np9 = :np9,
  np10 = :np10,
  np11 = :np11,
  np12 = :np12
  where team_id = :team_id";
```

Comment: @user2933231 oh yes. PHP and SQL are different. Please don't confuse between the two of them.